# Python: setting recursion limit slows sorting program

Tags: python, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I'm doing a program, that compares different sorting algorithms: insertion sort, bubble sort and quick sort. When the input is a list of at least 1000 elements, the program throws an error.

```
  File "/Users/karol/PycharmProjects/Algorytmy6/main.py", line 52, in quickSort
return quickSort(less) + equal + quickSort(greater)
  [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
  File "/Users/karol/PycharmProjects/Algorytmy6/main.py", line 43, in quickSort
    if len(list) > 1:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I tried to set recursion limit by `sys.setrecursionlimit(sizeOfList+1)`, but it dramatically slows the quick sort algorithm. For example for 10 000 elements in list, quick sort is slower than insertion sort:

> Insertion sorting a list of 10000 elements took: 3.238
>
> Bubble sorting a list of 10000 elements took: 5.618 s
>
> Quick sorting a list of 10000 elements took: 4.239 s

Moreover, if I run only quickSort algorithm without insertionSort and bubbleSort, then it works fine. And it is as fast as it should be:

> Quick sorting a list of 10000 elements took: 0.077 s

I need the real quickSort time, because the program was made to compare it with other sorting algorithms.

Here is my code:

```
import random, time

def insertionSort(list):
    startTime = time.time()
    for i in range(len(list)):
        min = list[i]
        for j in range(i, len(list)):
            if list[j] <= min:
                min = list[j]
                index = j
        list[index] = list[i]
        list[i] = min

    elapsedTime = round(time.time() - startTime, 3)
    print("Insertion sorting a list of {} elements took: {} s".format(len(list), elapsedTime))

    return list

def bubbleSort(list):
    startTime = time.time()
    n = len(list) - 1
    for j in range(len(list)):
        for i in range(n-j):
            if list[i] > list[i+1]:
                temp = list[i]
                list[i] = list[i+1]
                list[i+1] = temp


    elapsedTime = round(time.time() - startTime, 3)
    print("Bubble sorting a list of {} elements took: {} s".format(len(list), elapsedTime))

    return list

def quickSort(list):

    less = []
    equal = []
    greater = []

    if len(list) > 1:
        pivot = list[0]
        for x in list:
            if x < pivot:
                less.append(x)
            elif x == pivot:
                equal.append(x)
            elif x > pivot:
                greater.append(x)
        return quickSort(less) + equal + quickSort(greater)
    else:
        return list


size = 10000
list = [0]*size

for i in range(size):
    list[i] = random.randint(1, size)

insertionSort(list)
bubbleSort(list)
startTime = time.time()
quickSort(list)
elapsedTime = round(time.time() - startTime, 3)
print("Quick sorting a list of {} elements took: {} s".format(len(list), elapsedTime))
```

Comment: Your pivot selection is terrible. This is what happens when your pivot selection is terrible.

Comment: You're also mutating the input in two of your sorts.

Comment: Quicksort is notoriously much slower on a sorted list than on a randomly shuffled list. Try to call `insertionSort` and `bubbleSort` on copies of your list instead of on the original list, so that the original list remains unsorted. Note that you should **never** call a list `list` in python, because `list` is the name of the whole class `list`; shadowing that name will cause trouble. Instead call your list `myList`. You can make a copy using `myList[:]` or `list(myList)`; replace `insertionSort(myList)` with `insertionSort(list(myList))` to run insertion sort on copy instead of the original.

Comment: "Moreover, if I comment insertionSort and bubbleSort, quickSort doesn't need recursion limit anymore." um, what?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I changed the pivot selection for random, I didn't know that it is so important. Now the program works correctly, thanks. How do I mutate input?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm sorry, if it is incomprehensible. If I run only quickSort algorithm without insertionSort and bubbleSort, then it works fine.

Comment: The usual English phrase to say "remove a line by putting it in comment" is "comment out" instead of just "comment".

Comment: The problem is that you sort the list in the first two sorts so its sorted already when it reaches quicksort.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you sort the list in the first two sorts so its sorted already when it reaches quicksort

```
insertionSort(lst)
bubbleSort(lst)
quickSort(lst)
```

sorts the same list 3 times but it is already sorted after the first insertionSort.

You will need to copy the list sort from the original order.

```
import copy

lst_b = copy.deepcopy(lst)
lst_q = copy.deepcopy(lst)

insertionSort(lst)
bubbleSort(lst_b)
quickSort(lst_q)
```

The reason you see the problem with quickSort in your original code is that a sorted list leads to quadratic time when the list is already sorted.